# How can I migrate my divshot static website to firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, divshot

Per acquisition of Divshot.io by Google/Firebase.io, I am required to migrate my production "static" HTML app prior to 22-Dec-2015. I have installed the latest `firebase-tools` CLI and updated to the latest `divshot` CLI and otherwise prepared my environment.

I have followed all guidance from [divshot](http://docs.divshot.com/migrate) but receive the following error when trying to `deploy`:

```
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ cp -p divshot.production.json divshot.json
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ divshot migrate

Migrating Divshot app insider-web to Firebase Hosting

What is your Firebase project's name? (insider-web) insider
Can we anonymously report which features your app used (for Firebase Hosting roadmap planning, etc.)? (y/n) y
Write firebase.json? (y/n) y

⚠ Warning: The following incompatible features were detected.
- clean_urls support is planned for Firebase Hosting, but is not yet available
- Firebase Hosting does not support AJAX proxying

  Don't panic! Some features may be coming soon or there may be workarounds.
  Contact support@firebase.com with any questions.

You need to take the following actions to fully migrate your app:
- Rename error.html to 404.html

Wrote firebase.json configuration file.

If you have the latest version of firebase-tools you should now be able
to run firebase serve in this directory to start a local server and
firebase deploy to deploy to Firebase Hosting.

See http://docs.divshot.com/migrate for additional migration info.

Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $
```

I followed the guidance per renaming `error.html` to `404.html`:

```
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ cp -p error.html 404.html
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $
```

Looked good up to this point, but after attempting to deploy, I get this message:

```
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ firebase deploy

Error: Authentication required.
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $
```

Here is my original `divshot.json` file:

```
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ cat divshot.json
{
  "name": "insider-web",
  "root": "./",
  "clean_urls": true,
  "error_page": "error.html",
  "proxy": {
    "api": {
      "origin": "http://oa-mobile.herokuapp.com",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      },
      "cookies": false,
      "timeout": 30
    }
  }
}
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $
```

and here is the resulting `firebase.json` file:

```
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ cat firebase.json 
{
  "firebase": "insider",
  "public": "./",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $
```

Additional notes:
I am able to successfully run `firebase serve` and launch my app locally at `localhost:5000` - my initial landing page renders successfully and behaves correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login via the command line:

```
firebase login
```

This will open up a browser window for you to login via your Google account. Make sure it's the account that owns the `insider` Firebase app.

From what you have shwon, the only Firebase you currently own is named `glowing-heat-3960`. Change the `firebase` property in your `firebase.json`.

```
{
  "firebase": "glowing-heat-3960",
  "public": "./",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

After that you should be able to successfully deploy.

Comment: thanks - tried that, but still not working:

`Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ firebase login
Already logged in as jeff@insider.life
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ firebase deploy

Error: Authentication required.
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ `

Created my account on Firebase using my Google login

Comment: `Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ firebase --version
2.1.1
Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ 
`

Comment: Do a firebase list and see if insider belongs to the account

Comment: `Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ firebase list`  
`┌───────────────────┬──────┬────────────────────────┐`  
`│ Name              │ Plan │ Collaborators          │`  
`├───────────────────┼──────┼────────────────────────┤`  
`│ glowing-heat-3960 │ Free │ jeff.f@addresstalk.com │`  
`│                   │      │ jeff@insider.life      │`  
`└───────────────────┴──────┴────────────────────────┘`  
`Jeffs-rMBP:insider-web jeff [develop] $ `

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. In your `firebase.json` you're stating your Firebase app name is `insider`, when it's actually called `glowing-heat-3960`. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks - is the suggestion then to change the app name in the Firebase dashboard, or to change it in the `firebase.json` file?  Either way, there is nothing in the current guidance that indicates this.  Trying now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97577/discussion-between-jasper33-and-david-east).